# Trying To Make A ToString method that returns A Board

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm making a class for a driver program I got but because its doing,

```
System.println(game.toString());
```

I thought that I needed it to return a board.
I've have to make a toString method that returns a board with a character  2d array inside of it with each character of the array appearing in the board like this. 
(The number 2 is a character at 2d array[0][0]).

```
 ___________
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
| 2 |   |   |
|___|___|___|
```

The board represents a building and the class I'm making takes input from the user and produces this. in this case the user entered 5 floors and 3 rooms. The picture above represents that player 2 entered 0,0. Which causes the 2d array at [0][0] to become the character '2'.

This is my coding here and its not displaying what I want.

```
public String toString(){
       String Roof ="";
       for( int i = 0; i < room; i++){
            Roof += "  __";
        }
        Roof += "\n";
        String newLine = "\n";
        String walls = "|";
        for (int i = myHidingPlaces.length-1; i > 0 ; i--) {        
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < myHidingPlaces[0].length -1 ; j++){
                if(j >= myHidingPlaces[0].length -1){
                    walls += "\n";

                }else if(j < myHidingPlaces[0].length -1){
                    walls +=  myWinner+ " " + myHidingPlaces[i][j] + "|";
                }

            }

        }
 //                    "|__|__|__|\n";

        return  Roof + walls;//Arrays.toString(myHidingPlaces);  
    }
```

When I type 2 floors and 2 rooms
Here's what my coding it displays this:

```
  __  __
|    |
```

Comment: There are several extremely obvious mistakes here. Have you tried debugging or stepping through your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the toString method to get the following output.

```
 ___________ 
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   | 6 |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
|   |   |   |
|___|___|___|
```

Here's your code, modified to be runnable.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

public class Board {

    private String[][] myHidingPlaces;

    // private String myWinner;

    public Board() {
        // this.myWinner = "";
        this.myHidingPlaces = new String[3][5];
        initializeMyHidingPlaces();
    }

    private void initializeMyHidingPlaces() {
        for (int i = 0; i < myHidingPlaces.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myHidingPlaces[i].length; j++) {
                myHidingPlaces[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }
        myHidingPlaces[1][2] = "6";
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String wall = "|";

        builder.append(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < myHidingPlaces.length; i++) {
            if (i < (myHidingPlaces.length - 1)) {
                builder.append("____");
            } else {
                builder.append("___ ");
            }
        }
        builder.append(newLine);

        for (int i = (myHidingPlaces[0].length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myHidingPlaces.length; j++) {
                builder.append(wall);
                builder.append(" ");
                builder.append(myHidingPlaces[j][i]);
                builder.append(" ");
            }
            builder.append(wall);
            builder.append(newLine);

            for (int j = 0; j < myHidingPlaces.length; j++) {
                builder.append(wall);
                builder.append("___");
            }
            builder.append(wall);
            builder.append(newLine);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board();
        System.out.println(board);
    }

}
```